# Returning a SQL table from two compared column sum() aggregates on one column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, aggregate-functions

I have a working query that is compared with itself to find rows with a **difference** that is non-zero. This removes entries in the database that have the same **rxid** and if their difference  ( paid - obligcation) is **x** and **-x** respectfully.

What I think I need to use is an aggregate function because what I currently have does not remove multiple entries if there are more than 2 of the same ID but with a balanced difference ( for example three with differences of : x, -x/2, -x/2).

I have tried using sum() to get the total of the whole column for every rxid but I am unsuccessful at returning the row since what I am returning 'is not part of the aggregate function'. I Was told to use cursors, but I feel like this is such an integral part of relational databases that I'm missing something here.

```
WITH x
AS (
    SELECT IsInstyRxFlag
        ,pri.payerReceiptItemId
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, rx.oeDate, 101) rxOeDate
        ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 2), drx.payerOblig) payerObligation
        ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 2), pri.amountPaid) amountPaid
        ,pri.rxId
        ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 2), (pri.amountPaid - drx.payerOblig)) difference
        ,rxeventid
    FROM PayerReceiptItem pri
    JOIN Rx ON rx.rxId = pri.rxId
    JOIN DispenseRx drx ON rx.rxId = drx.rxId
    WHERE CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 2), drx.payerOblig) <> CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 2), pri.amountPaid)
        AND payerReceiptID = 19781
    )
SELECT x.*
FROM x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM x AS y
        WHERE x.amountpaid = - 1 * y.amountpaid
            AND x.difference = x.amountpaid
            AND x.rxid = y.rxid
        );
```

In this image, we see that we have two similar RXIDS of 45.00. There was one with 90 and another with -90 that got removed outside of this, but my sql code does not consider the sum.
[image: reversal img]

What I have been working on is a query that returns a sum on the RXID and its oblig and amountpaid. I am stuck on using exists or something to check areas where payeroblig <> amountpaid.

```
 select pri.RxID, (select SUM(drx.PAYEROBLIG)  from Dispenserx drx where   drx.RxID = pri.RxID) as payeroblig, (select SUM(pri1.AmountPaid)  from    PayerReceiptItem pri1 where pri1.RxID = pri.RxID and pri1.PayerReceiptID =   19781) as amountpaid  from PayerReceipt pr 
 join PayerReceiptItem pri on pri.PayerReceiptID = pr.PayerReceiptID
 JOIN DispenseRx drx ON pri.rxId = drx.rxId    
 where pr.PayerReceiptID=19781
```

[image: pic 2]

Lets take the code above, and then return one RXID that we would like to focus on. This has a payeroblig that is not the same as the amountpaid. This is the sum of all of the RXIDs in that column. This is an issue, they need to balance, and this would highlight that they do not match for this RXID
[image]

Comment: Uploaded in the Edit above.

Comment: Ok, I see the rows you mean in the results you are getting, and I see they both have different ReceiptItemId's.   What I don't understand is what results you want to get instead.

Comment: I would like to remove, for example, the entries of RXID=3349796. I can only do this with first set of code above if I make a RXID of 3349796 with a difference of +45. This cancels out the other two and leaves a balance problem. What I need is to just add an rxID = 3349796 but with a difference of +90. This needs to cancel out the two -45 differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return all rows where the **sum of the difference** is different from the **sum of the amountPaid**, I guess this should do the trick (not tested):

```
WITH x
AS (
    SELECT IsInstyRxFlag
        ,pri.payerReceiptItemId
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, rx.oeDate, 101) rxOeDate
        ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 2), drx.payerOblig) payerObligation
        ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 2), pri.amountPaid) amountPaid
        ,pri.rxId
        ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 2), (pri.amountPaid - drx.payerOblig)) difference
        ,rxeventid
    FROM PayerReceiptItem pri
    JOIN Rx ON rx.rxId = pri.rxId
    JOIN DispenseRx drx ON rx.rxId = drx.rxId
    WHERE CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 2), drx.payerOblig) <> CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 2), pri.amountPaid)
        AND payerReceiptID = 19781
    )
SELECT x.*
FROM x
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM x AS y
        WHERE y.rxId = x.rxId
        GROUP BY y.rxId
        HAVING SUM(y.amountpaid) <> SUM(y.difference)  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer to this thread is this:

```
 select distinct rxid, * from (select pri.RxID, (select SUM(drx.PAYEROBLIG)  from Dispenserx drx where drx.RxID = pri.RxID) as Sumpayeroblig, (select SUM(pri1.AmountPaid)  from PayerReceiptItem pri1 where pri1.RxID = pri.RxID and pri1.PayerReceiptID = 19781) as Sumamountpaid  from PayerReceipt pr 
  join PayerReceiptItem pri on pri.PayerReceiptID = pr.PayerReceiptID
 JOIN DispenseRx drx ON pri.rxId = drx.rxId 
 where pr.PayerReceiptID=19781) x 

 where x.Sumamountpaid <> x.Sumpayeroblig
```

This takes the aggregate sums of two tables, and then checks itself again with the column names. This returns 9 rows.